# How to Parametering in SSRS 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server

I have one project in that I am parameter company and product.

like I have two company Wipro and Acer for Wipro products are ' Bags and Laptop ' for or Acer products are ' Desktop and Mouse '

I am getting all graph..my problem is here.After selecting Wipro in company drop down,I go for Product drop down that time I getting all the products,like Wipro products and Acer products.
I don't wand like that.I need when I select Wipro from Company drop down I wand only Wipro product in product drop down.
Is it possible !!!
if it, help me please

Answer (score 0):

in order to populate data based on the 1st drop down ,you need to pass the Company name as the parameter for the 2nd dropdown.

Suppose i have 3 dataset

[image]

In `Company DataSet` i'm selecting only company name.

In `ProductDetails Dataset` ,i'm specifying a where clause to filter the data based on company Name

```
SELECT ProductName
FROM   Products
WHERE  (Name = @Name)
```

In `CompanyDetails Dataset` ,the query will be

```
SELECT  Name, ProductName, Location
FROM  CompanyDetails
WHERE (Name = @Name) AND (ProductName = @Product)
```

After writing the above queries ,you will see 2 parameters created named `@Name` and `@Product`

[image]

In the preview ,the report will now look like

[image]

Once you select Wipro ,you will get only Wipro related products in the 2nd drop down

[image]

This method is known as `cascading parameters` For more details refer [MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/05/26/ssrs-cascading-parameter-with-optional-select-all-in-sql-reporting-services-report.aspx)